# Include all resources in maven project in pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, pom.xml

I need to include all resources in my pom.xml but i didn't succeed. Indeed, I'm trying this code but i don't think it works for all resources

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>project/classifier</shadedClassifierName>
                <outputFile>shade\${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>fr.tse.fise2.pip.graphic.Main</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I think you need to add much more explanation of what you want to achieve and which error you get. Please _edit your question_ for that.

Comment: Done, error it's because i need src/main/resources but also favicon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

favicon should be in `src/main/resources` or a subfolder.

If you dont want to keep it there you can copy it using `maven-resources-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

I need to include all of my resources on the project named pip.

error it's juste because my includes in pom.xml don't include src/main/resources and main can't access to files in this folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9QvB.png)